# Pseudo-element and pseudo-class in component

Tags: css, google-chrome, web-component

I'm trying to style a native component.
These two work:

```
:host::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {}
:host(:hover) {}
```

but I don't know how to fix the following one:

```
:host::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {}
```

I tried to put the parentheses in different places to no avail.

***EDIT: SAMPLE CODE***

The sample code below uses the Shadow DOM and the styles are attached to it.

This is ***only supported in Chrome***, which is not a problem for me since I'm writing an Electron app.

Note that

```
:host::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: black;
}
```

doesn't work, while

```
<style>
    #elem::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background: black;
    }
</style>
```

does.

The last one is a workaround as it breaks encapsulation. In a complex app built from components, that's highly undesirable.

Here's the sample code ***WHICH WORKS ONLY IN CHROME***:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tnucpw6/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <style>
        #elem::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
            background: black;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        const css = `
          :host {
            position: absolute;
            overflow: auto;
            left: 20px;
            top: 20px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
          }
          
          :host::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 10px;
            background-color: rgb(36, 106, 153);
          }
          
          :host::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background-color: rgb(36, 106, 153);
            border-radius: 4px;
          }
          
          :host::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background: linear-gradient(rgb(253, 253, 134), rgb(165, 224, 243));
            border-radius: 4px;
            border: solid 1px rgb(6, 115, 193);
          }
          
          :host::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
            background: black;
          }
        `;
        
        function f() {
            const span = document.createElement('span');
            span.append('fdsasdfafsdafsdafdsadfsadfsadfsadfsafdsadsadasdsa');
            const root = document.createElement('div');
            root.append(span);
            root.id = 'elem';

            const shadowRoot = root.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
            shadowRoot.append(...root.childNodes);

            const styleSheet = new CSSStyleSheet;
            styleSheet.replaceSync(css);
            shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [styleSheet];

            const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            body.appendChild(root);
        }

        window.onload = () => {
            f();
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you inserting these properties within the shadow DOM?

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui Yes, in `adoptedStyleSheets`.

Comment: Could you share some more code, in a snippet or something? I want to have a look at the :host element and how your shadowDOM is interacting with it

Comment: I'm writing an Electron app so it's not so easy to share my code. I asked here just in case I was missing something obvious. I'll try to reproduce the problem with as little code as possible, but I'll call it a day for now. (Meaning, I should edit my question in a few days!)

Answer (score 0):

`:host` selects the host of the shadowDOM. Maybe instead of applying styles on the host through the shadowDOM, try directly applying the css to the element the normal way.

So if your host is called `.someElement`, then `.someElement::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover` should work. Or just see if you're able to change all scrollbar-thumbs with `*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover`

Comment: Please see the updated question. I'm not looking for a workaround. At least not yet.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with is to avoid `:host` altogether by wrapping the content of the component in an additional `div` so that that can be regarded as a virtual root, and we can apply the styles to that instead of the real root.

Encapsulation is preserved and everything works just fine. We just have a redundant div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <script>
        const css = `
          #virtroot {
            position: absolute;
            overflow: auto;
            left: 20px;
            top: 20px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
          }
          
          #virtroot::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 10px;
            background-color: rgb(36, 106, 153);
          }
          
          #virtroot::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background-color: rgb(36, 106, 153);
            border-radius: 4px;
          }
          
          #virtroot::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background: linear-gradient(rgb(253, 253, 134), rgb(165, 224, 243));
            border-radius: 4px;
            border: solid 1px rgb(6, 115, 193);
          }
          
          #virtroot::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
            background: black;
          }
        `;
        
        function f() {
            const span = document.createElement('span');
            span.append('fdsasdfafsdafsdafdsadfsadfsadfsadfsafdsadsadasdsa');
            const root = document.createElement('div');
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            root.append(div);
            div.append(span);
            div.id = 'virtroot';

            const shadowRoot = root.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
            shadowRoot.append(...root.childNodes);

            const styleSheet = new CSSStyleSheet;
            styleSheet.replaceSync(css);
            shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [styleSheet];

            const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            body.appendChild(root);
        }

        window.onload = () => {
            f();
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```